# font feature settings bug with letter spacing

Tags: css, google-chrome, opera, letter-spacing

I have a problem with with the `font-feature-settings` property in Chrome and Opera:
I want to use `'onum'` setting so I write, in the CSS, the following lines:

```css
-moz-font-feature-settings: 'onum' on;
 -ms-font-feature-settings: 'onum' on;
  -o-font-feature-settings: 'onum' on;
     font-feature-settings: 'onum' on;
-webkit-font-feature-settings: 'onum' on;
```

It works perfectly in Firefox and IE, but in Chrome and in Opera it generates a conflict with the `letter-spacing` property: if I use the `letter-spacing`, the `font-feature-settings` are completely ignored... why?

I'm using Chrome 40.0.2214.91 and Opera 26.0.1656.60 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Please be aware that there has never been support for `-o-font-feature-settings`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out: I just added `font-kerning: normal` and it worked

Comment: This worked for me too. Any idea why this makes it work?